# Encoding login-password pair

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

I have a login and password that I need to store in my database. What is a safer way to encode them (I use AES algorithm): as one string with separator between login/pass, or as a two separate strings?
Encoding has to be reversable, so please don't mention hash.

Comment: why reversible? for the login i get it, but for the password?

Comment: Maybe he's writing his own KeePass.

Comment: Sort of. These are passwords for some external services, and I need to transmit them decoded.

Comment: I think asking this question at http://security.stackexchange.com/ might give you more results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safety has not much to do with your choice. If you use `AES with mode different than ECB and PKCS7/PKCS5 Padding` you can either encrypt logins and passwords alone or logins and passwords seperately. It depends on wheather you will need a login without a password in your implementation. You will probably use the same key to encrypt both login and password. So splitting is by no means an additional security measure. If you woudl use some salted PKDF keys can be different for each record, but attacker still needs only to get the master password and a salt.

Comment: Any explanation, please?

Comment: Of AES? Of no additional security ?

Comment: It all boils down to "points of failure", If you use the same key to encrypt username and password separately, then you have one "point of failure" which means that if attacker gets your one key he can decrypt logins and passwords. You could use two keys, but it's problematic, where would you store them? would it be user based? Or global for the app? Maybe they would be based on PKDF function, if so would you force users to choose two passwords? one for login and one for password ? So in short it depends :), but probably not worth your time.

Answer (score 0):

That's no any additional security in encrypting them together or separately.
However, you should also choose wisely cipher mode/initial vector - for CBC and CTR (and CFB?) input to encryption is xored with encrypted Initial Vector, so having the same vector for two encrypted passwords, xoring them would allow to get xor of original passwords, which can leak information.